# MVC 4 Controller will not show view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller with a ActionResult I added after the initial build Named SubAlertModal

```
     [HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubAlertModal(int alertid)
{

    var SubAlerts = from sa in db.csSubAlerts
                    where sa.AlertID == alertid
                    select sa;

  //  csAlert cssubalert = db.csAlerts.Find(alertid);


 //   return View();

   return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? PartialView(SubAlerts) :   

       PartialView(SubAlerts);

}
```

on the Index.cshtml page I add an HTML.ActionLink  the looks like the folling

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Sub_Alert", "SubAlertModal", new { id = item.AlertID }, new { 
     @class = "ModalOpener" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Routes)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Issue)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Detour)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateEntered)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SendEmail)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.AlertID }, new {   
    @class="ModalOpener" }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id = item.AlertID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.AlertID})
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

the one inquestion is the first . 
when i click on the Sub_Alert in the list it gives me a 404 error.
the url is correct.
is the controller not matching up with the view.
this is the view i want to load in a modal window or any window at this point
    @model IEnumerable

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "SubAlerts";
 }

     <h2>SubAlert</h2>
<div id="SubAlertModal" title="Sub Alert for the Alert">
This is a test modal
and it appears to be working !!

<table>
<tr>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Issue)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Detour)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateEntered)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EnteredBy)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SendEmail)
    </th>
    <th></th>
 </tr>

  @foreach (var item in Model) {
 <tr>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Issue)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Detour)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateEntered)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SendEmail)
    </td>

</tr>
}

</table>



</div>
```

Thanks

Joe

Comment: What is your controller name? Home? If it is not Home you need to explicitly put in the controller name.

Comment: my controller name is AlertController and all my other actions work(Create, Edit, Detaills and Delete) Now I created the new actionresult named SubAlertModal(custom) but it should still wire up. when i click go to controller from the view it goes in vs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are accessing the action method via a link, then the HTTP verb is a GET, not a post.

Your action method is set up to only respond to a POST.

Simply remove `[HttpPost]` or change it to `[HttpGet]`

Comment: now i get this error?  The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'alertid' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SubAlertModal(Int32)' in 'MVC_CSAlerts.Controllers.AlertsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: if you haven't made any changes to routes - then change your `alertid` to `id` - as this would be the default parameter

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Sub_Alert", "SubAlertModal", new { alertid = item.AlertID }, new { @class = "ModalOpener" })